# Small Google Maps Infowindow - Smaller than 200px

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map_canvas with a width of 225.

I want my infobox to be smaller than this (eg. 150 px).

Is this possible? I tried maxWidth and adding styles, but nothing seemed to work.

A screen (on imgshack) can be found below: [image]

Also,
I'm using v3 of Google Maps

Javascript:

```
var results_coods;
var map_2;
var marker_2;
var infowindow_2;

function call_gmap()
{
if($('#map_text').attr('lat')){

    var lat = Number($('#map_text').attr('lat').replace(",","."));
    var lng = Number($('#map_text').attr('long').replace(",","."));
    initialize(lat,lng);
    /*
    var lat= '51.0153389';
    var lng = '2.7253832';  
    */

}
}

function initialize(lat,lng) {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: latlng,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        navigationControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
        draggable: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: $('#map_text').html(),
    maxWidth: 150
});

var image = 'beachflag.png';
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng, 
    map: map
});
infowindow.open(map,marker);
google.maps.event.addListener(
marker, 'click', function() {
   infowindow.open(map,marker);

}); 
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
map.setZoom( map.getZoom() );

}



function GcodeAddress() 
{
    var map;
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = $('#map_address').html();

     if (geocoder) {
      geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 13,
                center: results[0].geometry.location,
                navigationControl: false,
                scaleControl: false,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

              var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: $('#map_text').html()
              });

             map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            results_coods = results[0].geometry.location;
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map, 
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
            google.maps.event.addListener(
            marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            }); 

            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

            marker_2 = marker;
            map_2 = map;
           infowindow_2 = infowindow;
        } else {
          alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
      });
    }


}
function resizeMap()
{
    //hiervan komt 1 error, de andere van infowindow
    google.maps.event.trigger(map_2, 'resize');
    map_2.setCenter(results_coods);
    infowindow_2.open(map_2,marker_2);
}
```

Javascript, bottom of html page:
    
        $(document).ready(function($) {
            GcodeAddress();
            resizeMap();
        });

HTML (VB.Net):

```
    '-- Google Map

    g_map_text.Text = "<div id=""map_canvas"" style=""width: 225px; height: 225px;       position: relative;"" /></div>" & vbCrLf
    g_map_text.Text &= String.Format("<div id='map_text'      style=""display:none;width:150px;"">{0}</div>", LoadKantoor)
    g_map_text.Text &= String.Format("<div id='map_address' style='display:none;'      >{0}</div>", Bedrijf.Bedrijf("postalcode") & " " & Bedrijf.Bedrijf("city") & "," &      Bedrijf.Bedrijf("address"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier approach is to style using CSS.  You need wrap the contents of the infoWindow in a div with your custom CSS.

Javascript:

```
marker.openInfoWindowHtml('<div class="iwContainer">' + yourContent + '</div>');
```

CSS:

```
.iwContainer { 
  width: 300px; 
  height: 200px; 
}
```

Are you setting the maxWidth for the infowindow before the call to open as described [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#InfoWindowOptions)

EDIT:

I've looked at this again and it looks fine. I don't understand why it doesn't work.

You could use InfoBox.js instead?

API Reference: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html

Download JS: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/

Examples: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/examples/

Let me know how you get on.

Comment: The article described here is for v2.
I'm not able to resize the infowindow into a size smaller than 200px (haven't tried higher than that)

Comment: Yes,
In jQuery i add $('#map_text') as infowindow context.
Then i had <div id="map_text" style="width:250px;">contentforinfowindow</div>

Comment: @NicoJuicy - if the 3 options I have provided don't work for you, are you able to post your code?

Comment: added my code, sorry for the delay :) (thanks for your help though)

Comment: @NicoJuicy - I've added a few more links to my answer

Comment: I'd like to use the default infowindows :(
Even though, you are right.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703210/google-maps-v3-infowindow-too-wide (for more information)

I should try infobox then :(

Thanks though!

Comment: Yeah seems a bit strange how you can't do this with the Google API but InfoBox looks like a nice alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you interested using this infobubble:

```
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html/
```

you can apply css on this and easy to custom with the example